# aws emr cli failed for InvalidRequestException

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli, amazon-emr

I was able to run the `create-cluster` cli successfully and launched my EMR cluster, but when I tried to run below command to add a step:

```
aws emr add-steps --cluster-id j-your-cluster-id --steps Type=CUSTOM_JAR,Name=CustomJAR,ActionOnFailure=CONTINUE,Jar=s3://mybucket/mytest.jar,Args=arg1,arg2,arg3 Type=CUSTOM_JAR,Name=CustomJAR,ActionOnFailure=CONTINUE,Jar=s3://mybucket/mytest.jar,MainClass=mymainclass,Args=arg1,arg2,arg3 --profile my-test-account
```

it failed with this error:

```
An error occurred (InvalidRequestException) when calling the DescribeCluster operation: Cluster id 'j-your-cluster-id' is not valid.
```

and I've double checked `j-your-cluster-id` is matching my cluster-id exactly.

I feel like this is a permission issue, but how come the same profile could let me create a cluster, but cannot let me describe it?

How can I dig further and fix this please?

Comment: Maybe you run commend in different region and/or account you think you are?

Comment: I don't see specifiying region is an option for add steps: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/it_it/cli/latest/reference/emr/add-steps.html, if it's a wrong account, it'll throw other authentication exception, plus I've used `--profile my-test` to make sure it's talking to the right one.

Comment: And you see your cluster with `aws emr list-clusters`?

Comment: Actually, no, I can run this `list-clusters` command, it shows a list of clusters in this account, but none of them was the one that I just launched. I guess there's some configuration that's different for mine...

Comment: I would double check the region. You can sepcify region in aws cli using `--region` option for each command.

Comment: perfect! that's the key! I was able to run both "list-cluster" and "add-steps" command after specifying `--region`, thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad to hear it worked out. If you don't mind I will provide an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the comments.

The issue was caused by execution AWS CLI in **different region** than intended. The solution was to use [--region](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-options.html) option to provide correct region for the CLI.

Comment: Thanks @Marcin, just wanted to add on that: by default, `aws cli` points to `us-east-1` region, so if your resources on running in a different one, you'll want to specify it using `--region`. Thanks again!